# Django Channels - Group

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

If in a group there are two channels, after group_send the event chat.message is handled by chat_message.. and its happening for both the channels because I'm printing the channel names and getting two different names... but UI gets updated for only on consumer and that too twice, whereas the other consumer shows no changes.

In my client-side code, I have onmessage function, which is responsible for my UI getting updated.
The ideal case is if I have two channels in the same group then the message should be broadcast to both and thus UI of both consumers should get updated.

```
class MyWebsocketConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        print("Connected...",self.channel_name)
        self.group_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['group_name']
        # print('Group Name...',self.group_name)

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(self.group_name,{
        "type": "chat.message",
        "msg": text_data,
    },)
        
    def chat_message(self,event):
        self.send(text_data = event['msg'])
        print(self.channel_name)


    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(self.group_name, self.channel_name)


ws.onmessage = function(event){
            console.log('Message recived from server...', event)

            document.getElementById('chat-log').value += (event.data + '\n')
}
```